# Integrate Firebase Crashlytics (beta) SDK in iOS project without PODS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase, crashlytics

I am integrating FrirebaseCrashlytics SDK in tvOS and iOS without cocopods. I downloaded their xcFramework. But I can't use the xcFramework as the project is not compatible so I drag and drop ios-armv7_arm64 framework to project and added Firebase.h and module.modulemap (my project uses both objc and swift). Also, I specified the Firebase.h in the bridging header. I get below error when I build.

Showing Recent Errors Only

/Users/xxxxx/Code/ios/tvOSApplications/App/App/Firebase.h:15:9: 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found

Showing Recent Errors Only

/Users/xxxxx/Code/ios/tvOSApplications/App/App/App-tvOS-Bridging-Header.h:27:9: Could not build module 'Firebase'

Answer (score 1):

Multiple problems to address (based on instructions in the [README](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/ZipBuilder/Template/README.md) at the base of the distribution:

- The zip distribution requires Xcode 11 which supports xcframeworks
- The zip distribution only supports iOS. tvOS is only distributed via CocoaPods
- All Firebase installations require the xcframeworks in the Analytics folder to also be installed.

Comment: All who are want to use this without pods should follow above instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get firebasecrashlytic .framework files without cocopods using Carthage. I copied [image] files to project and it works in iOS project. I am looking for a similar solution for tvOS

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had a similar requirement of supporting Firebase on both iOS and tvOS. As the frameworks are available only on iOS and not on tvOS. I could not integrate Frameworks. So the solution I followed is adding of Source files provided in https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk corresponding to the required modules that are needed for enabling Firebase Crashlytics.

This solution worked for me and able to see the crashes. Let me know if you need more information

Comment: How you added source file, i need to implement crash and notification  both

Comment: Here is the solution https://medium.com/@Javan.Poirier/integrating-firebase-crashlytics-for-tvos-without-cocoapods-or-xcframework-support-a8f4b389c7c2

Answer (score 0):

I got Firebase Crashlytics working for tvOS without Cocoapods or XCFramework bundles. Basically, you just need to bring over the source files, set the header search paths, and set all the required preprocessor macros. You can read the story [here](https://medium.com/@Javan.Poirier/integrating-firebase-crashlytics-for-tvos-without-cocoapods-or-xcframework-support-a8f4b389c7c2).

Thanks for the hint Gangadhar!